# Nodemon server won't start

Tags: node.js

I was trying to create a simple room based webchat app using socket.io. But I've been facing issues with serving the node server file with node and nodemon. I've tried different ports i.e., 8000, 8080, 80 and I've also tried reinstalling node and nodemon both locally and globally but nothing seems to work. I guess the code is alright because I was following a tutorial (that didn't include any link to the source code though). I'm on windows so I've also used used the command

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

Here are the screenshots of Windows power shell and command prompt

[image: The screenshot of the issue in power shell]

[image: The screenshot of the same issue in cmd]

**PS: I am a newbie, so please consider that I might have missed something basic.**

```
const io = require('socket.io')(8000)
const users = {};

io.on('connection', socket =>{
    socket.on('new-user-joined',name =>{
        users[socket.id] = name;
        socket.broadcast.emit('user-joined', name);
    });
    socket.on('send', message =>{
        socket.broadcast.emit('receive', {message: message,name: user[socket.id]});
    });
})
```

Comment: If you want people to help you, you'll have to compose a better question. This will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. As a start I suggest posting your package.json and the actual error you get when you try to run nodemon.

Comment: What is the error exactly?

Comment: @Tibebes.M no error it just gets stuck at starting as shown in the screenshot above. It doesn't show the message it shows when it successfully creates the server.

Comment: @RobertMoskal Thanks, I'll make sure to read it and compose questions accordingly.

Comment: how are you triggering it? that should be the issue

Comment: It looks like it's working correctly to me.  I'd suggest following along with https://socket.io/get-started/chat/ to learn socket.io

Comment: everything looks perfect to me, nodemon is running as it should be, but for the future, I would suggest, and it's a good practice to add this at the end 
if you are using express (`App.listen(3000, function (req, res) {
  console.log("Server started");
});` this will help you to determine whether your project is working fine or not or in plain terms whether it is started or not ;)

Comment: don't use powershell, use git bash instead